# Simple Adapter to show part of List (made with Hashmap) by keyword

Tags: android, list, android-listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

I have but of a problem. I've made a list as following:

```
List<Map<String, String>> ShopsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
       private void initList() {
        // We add the cities
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "Broer Bretel"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "Caffènation"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "Caffènation - Take Out Nation"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "Coffeelabs"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "De Dikke Kat"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Antwerpen", "Mlle Loustache")); 
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Berchem", "Broer Bretel"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Berchem", "Caffènation"));
           ShopsList.add(createShop("Berchem", "Caffènation - Take Out Nation"));
```

and

```
private HashMap<String, String> createShop(String key, String name) {
        HashMap<String, String> shop = new HashMap<String, String>();
        shop.put(key, name);
        return shop;
       }
```

So now I use SimpleAdapter to diplay this list in a Listview. But what I want is to be able to only show the data from the list with a specific keyword. So I do

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, ShopsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] {"Antwerpen"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
```

When I do this, he only shows me the data with the right keyword, but adds the other entry's as empty. So when I ask for the second keyword, he first adds 6 empty places before displaying the right entry's.

How should I do this? I think I should add the locations of the entry's with the wanted keyword, but how do I retrieve these locations in an easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:**

as it was pointed out, I mistaken SimpleAdapter with ArrayAdapter. Apologies and if you want to change your implementation to an ArrayAdapter (which is much simpler IMHO), the code is below.

**original:**

When filling up the `android.R.id.text1` with the values, the `ArrayAdapter` just calls `.toString()` in each element from the List.

There're several ways to accomplish what you want.

- One of them would be to make a `List<String>` and just make the `Strings` as you want to be seen on the screen.
- A valid more "O.O." approach is to create your own class.

for example:

```
public class Shop{
   private String city;
   private String name;

   public Shop(String city, String name){
       this.city = city;
       this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return city + " - " + name
   }
}
```

and then on your adapter you'll use a `List<Shop>` instead of a map. and by overriding the `toString()` method you can manipulate the text as you wish.

- just to mention, another way of doing it could be a extending the ListAdapter class

Comment: I like the idee of defining a class, especially since I have to implement more info per shop in a later stage. But I don't see how I can specify my adapter then so my list only shows the shops from one specific city

Comment: you have to filter before passing the data to the adapter. For example, if it comes from a databases, you have to filter on the SELECT query. If it comes from an online API, check if the API have does supply filtering. If all of those fail, you can do it manually creating a 'filtered' List before passing to the Adapter